# How do you calculate distance to origin for a random point in {−3,−1,1,3}×{−4,−2,2,4}?

Tags: probability

The question is if this sample space is uniform:

{distance to origin} for a random point in {−3, −1, 1, 3} × {−4, −2, 2, 4}

How do you calculate each distance to origin?

Comment: Well... you could do the cartesian product so you will get points of the form $(x_i,y_i)$. Then $\operatorname{dist}((x_i,y_i),(0,0))=\sqrt{(x_i-0)^2+(y_i-0)^2}=\sqrt{\smash[b]{x_i^2+y_i^2}}$.

Comment: That is an answer, @manooooh .  Post it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome!

A cartesian product $A\times B$ is a set which contains a pair of elements of the set $A$ as first element, and elements of $B$ as second element. Formally, $$A\times B=\{(x,y)\mid \text{$x\in A$ and $y\in B$}\}.$$ So for example, if you have $\{0,1\}\times\{0,4\}$ you will get $\{0,1\}\times\{0,4\}=\{(0,0),(0,4),(1,0),(1,4)\}$.

Once you find all the elements of the cartesian product, you can use the formula of distance between two points in 2D: if $P=(x,y)$ and $Q=(z,t)$ are two points in two dimensions, then the distance between them is $$\operatorname{dist}(P,Q)=\operatorname{dist}(Q,P)=\sqrt{(x-z)^2+(y-t)^2}.$$ Do these calculations for every point... or think about a possible **symmetry** between e.g. points $(-3,4)$ and $(3,4)$.

Comment: Thank you!! Very helpful!

Comment: @b3llegsd you are welcome! You can accept it by clicking the checkmark below the "V".